# Connect.js static middleware and coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript, middleware, node.js-connect

I am trying to learn to use the Connect.js static middleware, but all the examples I find use the static command as either a function, or a getter, some use a method called use(), while others don't. Frankly, I'm stumped.

I am doing this in CoffeeScript.  Here is my code:

```
connect = require 'connect'
fs = require 'fs'

server = connect.createServer (req,res)->
 console.log 'Incoming Request:' + req.url
 connect.static(__dirname="/static");
 fs.readFile 'index.html',  (err,data)->

  if not err
    res.write data
    res.end()
server.listen 7243
```

The index.html has a .jpg file that is in the /static directory. The index.html file is served, but the image always appears as a broken link. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Any info will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should change

```
connect.static(__dirname="/static");
```

to the correct

```
connect.static(__dirname+"/static");
```

or the longer

```
connect.static("#{__dirname}/static");
```